# getting only last id in php

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have total 7 Id in MySQL table. and I am fetching those Id's from database

code is :

```
<form class="form-inline"  method="POST" action="book.php">
<div class="row-fluid home">
    <div class="span3">


    <?php
        $query=mysql_query("select * from category");
        $cat_count = 0;
        while($result=mysql_fetch_array($query))
        {
            $category_id=$result['cat_id'];
            $category_type=$result['cat_type'];
            $categroy_desc=$result['cat_desc'];
            $category_image=$result['cat_images'];
            $category_price=$result['cat_price'];
            $cat_count += 1;
            //$_SESSION["session_category_id"] = $category_id;
    ?>      
<div  class="room_selector" data-price="<?php echo $category_price; ?>" data-adults="4" data-kids="2"
<?php if ($cat_count!=1) {echo 'style="display: none;"'; } ?> >

            <h5>
                <a href="index.php?id=<?php echo $category_id; ?>" class="pull-left">
                    <i class="icon-chevron-left"></i>
                </a>                           
                    <?php echo $category_type; ?>                       
                <a href="index.php?id=<?php echo $category_id; ?>" class="pull-right ">             
                    <i class="icon-chevron-right"></i>
                </a>
            </h5>               
                <a class="iframe" href="rooms.php">             
                  <img src="data:image/png;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($category_image); ?>" alt="No Photo" />              
                </a>

               <p><?php echo $categroy_desc;?></p><br><Br><bR>
               <!--<a class="btn btn-primary btn-large book-now" name="submit" type="submit" href="book.php?id=<?php echo $category_id; ?>">
               Check Availability!</a>-->
             <?php echo $x=$category_id;
            ?>
              <input type="hidden" name="cat_id" value="<?php echo $category_id; ?>">
            <?php  $users[] = $result['cat_id'];?>
</div>

            <?php
        }
        ?> 
          <?php echo $category_id; 
        ?>

    </div>      
    <div class="span3 home_calendar">
                    <div class="form-horizontal">           
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label pull-left" for="inputEmail">Arrive</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" value=""  name="from" class="span2 check-in-date" value="2015/05/22" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="datepicker_from"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="span3 home_calendar">
                    <div class="form-horizontal">           
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label pull-left" for="inputEmail">Depart</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" value=""  name="to" class="span2 check-out-date" value="2015/05/27" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="datepicker_to"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="span3">
        <div class="form-horizontal">

            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Rooms</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <select class="span1 select_rooms" name="no_of_selected_room">
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                        <option>4</option>
                        <option>5</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>          


            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Adults per room</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <select class="span1 select_adults" name="no_of_adults">
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>                          
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Kids per room</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <select class="span1 select_kids" name="no_of_kids">
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                        <option>4</option>
                        <option>5</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">extra person</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <select class="span1 select_kids">
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>                          
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>


            </div>
    <div id="total_price" class="price" name="price"></div>

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large book-now" name="submit" value="Check  Availability!">
    <!--<a class="btn btn-primary btn-large book-now"  type="submit" href="book.php?id=">Check Availability!</a>--> 


</div>
```

The `$category_id` is the main key to my project. once user will select the room then the `$category_id` will select based on that.

I am trying to send this `id` to other page using one form
//book.php

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{    

 $n_cat_from = $_POST['from'];
 $n_cat_to = $_POST['to'];
 $n_no_of_selected_rooms = $_POST['no_of_selected_room'];
 $n_no_of_adults = $_POST['no_of_adults'];
 $n_no_of_kids = $_POST['no_of_kids'];

 $current_Category_id = $_POST['cat_id'];

 echo "id;;;;;;;;;;;;" . $current_Category_id;
}       
?>
```

When I try to `echo` that `id` I am getting only last id in the database (after user selecting different id also )

where I am wrong ? why it is taking last Id ? help me

Comment: Is the `<form>` inside the `while` loop?

Comment: It is already an array @Uchiha

Comment: while loop is inside the form only

Comment: Are you getting 7 divs on execution of the above code?

Comment: I'm not seeing the form in your code

Comment: Post your entire form code

Comment: Yes form is no where to be seen. Please share form code as well.

Comment: i have edited my code please check

Comment: you are using `mysql_fetch_array` but need associated data, so instead use `mysql_fetch_assoc` but I'd suggest not to use `mysql_` functions any more, better use `PDO`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1

Comment: did you manage to get there?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to store multiple values in a hidden input with the same name, you have to add `[]` after the name, like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="cat_id[]" value="<?php echo $category_id; ?>">
        <?php  $users[] = $result['cat_id'];?>
```

this way, you should have an array in book.php:

```
$_POST[cat_id] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 5 [5] => 6 [6] => 7 )
```